# Why I need to use WebDriver instead of ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am Working on a project there we need to run our tests only on chrome browser. We don't need any other browsers.

instead of

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Can I use

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

What is the disadvantage when I use ChromeDriver instead of WebDriver?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/upcasting-vs-downcasting-in-java/

This is called upcasting ,

As mentioned in the other answer,

> ChromeDriver class extends RemoteWebDriver class. RemoteWebDriver
> class implements WebDriver interface

so if you declare the identifier as Chromedriver type :

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
```

Then only methods defined in the ChromeDriver class will be exposed. So we are upcasting it to the highest level which is the WebDriver interface so that **all methods in WebDriver interface, and overridden in RemoteWebDriver, and ChromeDriver class are available in the object instance**.

This help us to use the same variable to initialize different types of drivers as only methods implemented/defined by the web driver class is used.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver()
```

etc..

read more at : http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/02/08/why-do-we-up-cast-browser-driver-class-object-to-webdriver/

Comment: Are there methods defined in  WebDriver interface that are not implemented by ChromeDriver? Also, if there are some such methods, since we are initializing the driver as instance of ChromeDriver by `new ChromeDriver()`, we still will not be able to use them since ChromeDriver doesn't implement them anyway.

Comment: @Prophet class documentation is the right place always , read the methods inherited section : https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have read it, but couldn't find something that is existing in WebDriver interface and is missing in ChromeDriver. What am I missing?

Comment: @prophet it says methods inherited from remotewevdriver methods , it means those methods which are mentioned is actually from parent ,not implemented by chrome driver alone ,

Comment: I think i understand this. But I still can't understand how driver defined by `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` will be missing some methods that will be available if I define it as `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`? I can think about the opposite: since there are several methods introduced in RemoteWebDriver defining driver as `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` will be missing all them.

Comment: @Prophet thats correct so if yo udefine ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() then only methods defined in the ChromeDriver class can be used. So when you want to create a Firefox test again you have to create new FireFox Driver variable, if you use WebDriver , then method exposed by parent (which is the webdriver) and over written by the child will be used. So you cna work with many drivers using same script

Comment: @Prophet http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/02/08/why-do-we-up-cast-browser-driver-class-object-to-webdriver/ this is really lovely article

Comment: Thanks a lot for an interesting articles! Indeed. But, in the bottom line, your answer is actually explains much more and much deeper, but the conclusion is the exactly what I wrote in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use.

`ChromeDriver` class extends `RemoteWebDriver` class. `RemoteWebDriver class implements WebDriver interface`

See what official [says here](http://A%20WebDriver%20implementation%20that%20controls%20a%20Chrome%20browser%20running%20on%20the%20local%20machine) about chromedriver

> A WebDriver implementation that controls a Chrome browser running on
> the local machine.

There are more than 7 classes that extends from `RemoteWebDriver` so if you declare driver like this :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

This means that type of driver is WebDriver type and it's not specific so you can change browser or implement `cross browser automation testing`.

But if you do

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

You can not achieve cross browser testing.

Comment: i didn't down vote, but its the other way , webdriver is the interface and remotewebdrier is the class https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html

Comment: @PDHide : I have mentioned the same thing : ) . Read this in the first line `RemoteWebDriver class implements WebDriver interface`

Answer (score 0):

The only disadvantage of using `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` is that you will not be able to use your code with any other browser in the future.
So, while currently you are using Chrome only there is no difference, but it's just unnecessary limitation for future use since using `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` instead of `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` also doesn't give you any advantage.